# Is there a way to have spring run additional code at application startup failure?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

We have a spring web-application running on a Tomcat server that we would like to have some additional code run ONLY if there is an issue with the webapp's startup.

However, any errors we receive will come from either Bean Creation Issues (which, hopefully we would catch before ever releasing) or a Flyway upgrade script issue. Both cases, the exceptions are caught within the spring core somewhere, and I'd like to run some additional code in those situations before the webapp failure finishes. I'm not 100% sure how to set this up though, considering where the exceptions are thrown.

I've been looking at Spring's Life Cycle configuration annotations, and while I have considered running the code in the @PreDestroy method we're providing, that means it would run our code every time we restarted the webapp, instead of just on startup failures. Is there a way to indicate the differences between a normal shutdown and a failed startup using the life cycle annotations?

Comment: What is the whole picture, what kind of code are you trying to run on "failure"?

Comment: @RC For some of our web apps, when we're doing initialization, if we come across failures we shoot a sort of "911" email to indicate something's wrong (mostly because these updates are done overnight.) The typical examples of doing this are when we are doing program-specific setup and issues arise. However, one of our services has become a critical system, and we want to know immediately if it has failed to startup, rather than waiting for phone calls on it.

Comment: You should probably use some external monitoring to do that, if your app crashes (let's say you get an OOM error), there's a good chance you'll never get an email.

Answer (score 2):

You could register your own `ServletContextListener` instead of the Spring's one and delegate `contextInitialized` method invocation to the Spring implementation you use for loading Spring context (whichever one you use, for example `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`).

Then catch and handle the desired exceptions.